# iPhone local file path

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dropbox

I have integrated dropbox in my app. I have it up to the point where it displays the files to the user and they can select the ones to download. I know I need to call this line but I don't know what the local file path on an iPhone is. It only needs to be temporary because once I have the text file I will process it... My question is what is the local file path. Thank You in advance.

```
[[self restClient] loadFile:[filePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intoPath:localPath]
```

UPDATED BASED ON ANSWER BELLOW:::STILL NOT WORKING

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSString *localPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:[filePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [[self restClient] loadFile:[filePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intoPath:localPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:localPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you usually just use your local document directory.

Try this:

`NSString *localPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:[filePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPathStore2 stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'

Comment: are you sure that `[filePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is not null?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for:

```
NSString * tempPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSTemporaryDirectory(), NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * yourFile = [filePaths objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if(yourFile != nil) {
    NSString * filePath = [tempPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:yourFile];
}
else {
    // Check your file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For historic reasons the need for a temp directory existed in Unix long before Objective-C. So the way to get the temp directory in our language is crafted on top of an existing Unix method using confstr. It’s also in NSPathUtilities for your convenience.

```
NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *tmpFile = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.txt"];
```